# Order of calculation for multiple successive division operations in a single term

Tags: matlab, division, operator-precedence, function-handle

Why does this function handle in Matlab `g = @(x)(4*x^5-A)/5/x^4;` correspond to 
`g(x) = (4x^5-A)/5x^4` and not to `(4x^5-A)/(5/x^4)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are observing is the [left associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) of the division operator. Maybe we should simplify the example first, no anonymous function, just the operators:

```
>> 5/5/5
ans =
    0.2000
>> (5/5)/5
ans =
    0.2000
>> 5/(5/5)
ans =
     5
>>
```

There isn't really a logical reason behind, but all programming languages I know have math operators like `/` left associative. `*` is also left associative, but it usually does not matter. When it comes to order of operation, also consider the [precedence](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html).